# Conditional versions/process with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I have this uploader class

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  process :resize_to_limit => [300, 300]

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [50, 50]
  end

 ...
```

Which will process the original file to 300x300 and save a thumb version.

I would like to be able to make a small/thumb version only based on a boolean on my model?

So I did this

```
if :icon_only?
 process :resize_to_limit => [50, 50]
else
  process :resize_to_limit => [300, 300]
end

protected

 def icon_only? picture
   model.icon_only?
 end
```

But it always ended up in 50x50 processing. Even when I did like this

```
 def icon_only? picture
   false
 end
```

I might got my syntax up all wrong with the : but i also tried asking

```
if icon_only?
```

Which told me there was no method name like that.Im lost...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an `:if` conditional, like so:

```
process :resize_to_limit => [50, 50], :if => :icon_only?
process :resize_to_limit => [300, 300], :if => ...
```

I haven't actually tried this but it's documented [in the code](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb#L20), so it should work.

Comment: I got this part working

      process :resize_to_limit => [50, 50], :if => :icon_only? 
      process :resize_to_limit => [300, 300], :if => !:icon_only?

But it always creates the thumb version even the unless statement

  version :thumb, :unless => :icon_only? 

  version :thumb do 
    process :resize_to_limit => [50, 50]
  end

Comment: I don't think `:if => !:icon_only?` will work. Either define another function `:not_icon_only?` or use a proc: `process :resize_to_limit => [300, 300], :if => Proc.new { !icon_only? }`. Also are you sure your `icon_only?` method is actually working? It takes an argument `picture` but then you call `icon_only?` on `model`.

Comment: Well it seemed like a mess so I ended up making another uploader class just for my icon. My icon_only? method (on the model) did not take the newly assigned value as well, it only go the default value from the table so even if i got the logic to work i dont how how I could determine if it should be a an icon only or not. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @shioyama calling `model` works. It is probably an accessor method

Answer (score 2):

As @shioyama pointed out, one can use :if to specify the condition.

However, doing the inverse condition (e.g. `!icon_only?`) requires a bit of work.

```
process :resize_to_limit => [300, 300], :if => Proc.new {|version, options| !version.send(:icon_only?, options[:file])} do
```